# How to execute .jar file from AWS Lambda Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jar, aws-lambda, serverless

I have tried with following code.

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
  var runCmd = 'java -jar ' + process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT + '/src/' + 'myjar.jar'

  exec(runCmd,
    function (err, resp) {
      if (err) {
        cb(null, { err: err})

      } else {
        cb(null, { resp: resp})
      }
    )
```

Here, I have put my jar file in the root folder and src folder also.
but it is giving my following error. I have already added the.jar file with the code.but i got following error.

```
"err": {
    "code": "ENOENT",
    "errno": "ENOENT",
    "syscall": "spawn java -jar /var/task/src/myjar.jar",
    "path": "java -jar /var/task/src/myjar.jar",
    "spawnargs": [],
    "cmd": "java -jar /var/task/src/myjar.jar"
}
```

So How, Can I execute this .jar file in AWS Lambda environment?
Please help me.

Comment: One suggestion: you can deploy the functionality in jar as separate lambda and then call that lambda from this primary lambda :)

Comment: 2 questions:
1. Did you upload the java runtime binary to Lambda, I might be wrong, but I don't believe Lambda provides this by default, especially the nodejs runtime.
2. Did you test your function locally to ensure that the path is right?
i'd also recommend that you check out: https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/ and try to see if it runs properly

Comment: curious if you got this working using a lambda layer?

Answer (score 7):

With Lambda Layers you can now bring in multiple runtimes.

https://github.com/lambci/yumda and https://github.com/mthenw/awesome-layers both have a lot of prebuilt packages that you can use to create a layer so you have a second runtime available in your environment.

For instance, I'm currently working on a project that uses the Ruby 2.5 runtime on top of a custom layer built from lambci/yumbda to provide Java.

```
    mkdir dependencies
    docker run --rm -v "$PWD"/dependencies:/lambda/opt lambci/yumda:1 yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64
    cd dependencies
    zip -yr ../javaLayer .
```

1. upload javaLayer.zip to aws lambda as a layer
2. add layer to your function
3. within your function, java will be located at /opt/lib/jvm/{YOUR_SPECIFIC_JAVA_VERSION}/jre/bin/java

Comment: Thanks for this @Kosmonaut , I use something similar but with NodeJS, and I need java as I "spawn" a jar , Does your ruby code, find java in path, did you require to set JAVA_HOME or Java path , I am using exact steps, you used, what java version should I give in above path you mentioned in step 3 if I need to?

Comment: Now the error I am getting is Error: Error: could not find libjava.so
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment , any clue?

Answer (score 5):

AWS Lambda lets you select a `runtime` at the time of creation of that lambda function, or later you can change it again.
[image]

So, as you are running the Lambda function with `NodeJs` runtime, the container will not have `Java` runtime available to it.

You can only have one type of `runtime` in one container in case of AWS Lambda.

So, Create a separate Lambda with the `Jar` file that you want to run having Java as the `runtime` and then you can trigger that lambda function from your current `NodeJS` lambda function if that's what you ultimately want.

Following is an example of how you can call another Lambda function using `NodeJS`

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new aws.Lambda({
  region: 'put_your_region_here'
});

lambda.invoke({
  FunctionName: 'lambda_function_name',
  Payload: JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    context.done('error', error);
  }
  if(data.Payload){
   context.succeed(data.Payload)
  }
});
```

You can refer to the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: Since 2020 December, Lambda supports container images: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/

Ex.: I created a container image using AWS's open-source base image for python, adding a line to install java. One thing my python code did was execute a .jar file using a sys call.

Comment: Hey @Zachary , how did you install java? I am using apt-get command but getting error `apt-get: command not found`

Comment: RUN yum install -y \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/